# How to make any Java method static at run time?

Tags: java

I am wondering if there is any way to achieve the following.

1. Find a method using reflection (done)
2. Change the method access modifier to to public and static. (How?)
3. execute this method without having any existing instance (How?)

Does reflection has any option to do this?

Comment: I hate it when people respond like Iam gonna do now, but, why do you want to do this?

Comment: @Viktor: I think "why?" is a perfectly reasonable comment.

Comment: @vector; I have got a API, I need to execute a method of one of the class in the API. This class is final, and object creation process is very expensive(I don't even have access to all the required resources). So, I was wondering if this can be a option.

Comment: chances are the method is non static because it uses some instance variable and so it will not be possible to call it without an instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is completely impossible and makes no sense whatsoever. An instance method has access to (and typically uses) instance variables. What should e.g. a typical set or get method that has been "made static" possibly do?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't make any sense.  A non-static method is non-static for a reason, in that it needs to access member data *specific to a particular instance of the class*.  How would you convert that to static?

Answer (score 1):

Even if you used tools that let you change a class (like BCEL), you still wouldn't have achieved anything, because (all minor caveats aside) the moment you change a method from instance method to static, all code calling it will throw a `NoSuchMethodError`. The reason being that invoking a static/instance method use two different opcodes.

Comment: Moreover you cannot make method static automatically. Static method cannot call other non-static methods or variables. So actually to be safe you have to change all methods to be static. But what do you achieve in this case? Just creating instance and calling its non-static methods does the same effect.

Comment: @AlexR: >>Moreover you cannot make method static automatically<<. Technically you can during class loading to alter the signatures or add the static method. But non-static methods have more parameters and aload0 is actually 'this'

Comment: @AlexR This is what I euphemastically labelled "minor caveats". But you're right, there are a thousand reasons why this wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can't change a class with reflection. You can just inspect it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible.

If your method uses a 'this' reference, that would be an undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

As all said this is bad and should not be done.

But again if you have to achieve this and you have already given the reason so I might like to try something different to achieve this.
I might create a singleton class and give a static method (facade) to access the required API method and always make sure that all other classes use this singleton class method to access the API method.